# DAO implementation in java

Tags: java, dao, implementation

When we create Data Access Object layer in java, we declare methods for insert,update and delete data. Should we use synchronization for these methods??
Because i think lots of users can save,update and delete data at the same time.

Please help.

Comment: Dao implementations uses session factories and using this session factory creates sessions and make queries. Those sessionFactories are thread safe and need to be taken care explicitily

Comment: and if i am using simple spring jdbc implementation, can i use session factories.

Comment: Yes you can use session factories in spring jdbc implementation and would be thread safe..

Comment: even i am using this code:org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

Comment: can you provide the sample code which you are using.

Comment: '<beans>
    <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/newdatabase"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>'

Comment: where have you used this bean?

Comment: The datasource which you create here is used by JDBCTemplate, which is   used to make JDBC call and this class is thread safe as per the documentation provided by spring

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I GOT IT.

Answer (score 2):

No, because your DAO itself should be stateless. The various users' operations should be coordinated using database transactions, not JVM synchronization.

(And if practical, you should avoid writing DAOs in the first place, if some tool such as Spring Data can autogenerate them for you.)

Comment: If i am using spring with its jdbctemplate implementation, should i use Synchronization. or database will handle all the synchronization automatically, if i using mysql database.